# Add conditional counter in new column R

Tags: r, counter

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
form = c("test", "test", "missing", "test", "test", "missing", 
"test", "test", "test", "missing")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

| id | form |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | missing |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | test |
| 2 | missing |
| 2 | test |
| 3 | test |
| 3 | test |
| 3 | missing |

I need to add a column ("form_completed") that starts counting from 1 by "id", but skips the counting for a certain value under "form" which is a string variable. The output should be:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
form = c("test", "test", "missing", "test", "test", "missing", 
"test", "test", "test", "missing"), form_completed = c(1L, 
2L, NA, 3L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

| id | form | form_completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 1 |
| 1 | test | 2 |
| 1 | missing | NA |
| 1 | test | 3 |
| 2 | test | 1 |
| 2 | missing | NA |
| 2 | test | 2 |
| 3 | test | 1 |
| 3 | test | 2 |
| 3 | missing | NA |

It seems pretty straightfoward, and I have tried different things with mutate() and row_count() in R, but can't find it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `dplyr`

You can use `case_when` + `cumsum`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(a = case_when(form == 'test' ~ cumsum(form == "test")))
```

```r
      id form        a
   <int> <chr>   <int>
 1     1 test        1
 2     1 test        2
 3     1 missing    NA
 4     1 test        3
 5     2 test        1
 6     2 missing    NA
 7     2 test        2
 8     3 test        1
 9     3 test        2
10     3 missing    NA
```

Or with `ifelse`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(a = ifelse(form == 'test', cumsum(form == "test"), NA))
```

---

#### `base R`

```r
df$a[df$form == "test"] <- with(df[df$form == "test", ], ave(form, id, FUN = seq_along))
```

```r
   id    form    a
1   1    test    1
2   1    test    2
3   1 missing <NA>
4   1    test    3
5   2    test    1
6   2 missing <NA>
7   2    test    2
8   3    test    1
9   3    test    2
10  3 missing <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you - both dyplr options worked :)